# Where to create folder for uploaded files in a Spring project?

Tags: java, spring, file, upload

I am making a Spring (not Boot!) project right now, with Maven. The user can upload a file, then I store it in the file system. When I start the application, I create a folder with a method annotated with @PostConstruct. I have already tried two ways: create the folder in the same level as the src and target folder, or create it in the target/tomcat folder (I used the ${catalina.base} property). I want to do some conversion on the uploaded file, basically convert it to JSON, and also store the JSON file. Then I want to use these two files inside JSP pages: when the user executes a GET request, my application will return the path of the files, and I want to use the content of the JSON with JavaScript.

So my question is basically: what is the best place to store these files, if I want to use them later for any purpose, and I dont want to use absolute paths. I saw some example when the code creates a folder like: "C:\folder", but that looks weird for me, relative is much better in my opinion.

Comment: This sounds like an excellent use case for a database.

Comment: Yes, of course Im gonna store the path of the files in a database, but the main question was where to store the files?

Comment: Be sure to consider security.  Since the URL to the resource (file/database record) will be visible to the user make sure the user cannot hack the URL and gain access to some other user's file/record.

Comment: Sure, but I am suggesting that storing the files as files seems unnecessary in the first place. What does it buy you?

Comment: So you saying that maybe I can store my files directly in the database?

Comment: Check out the [CLOB](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_large_object) sql type for storing JSON in your database.

Comment: That depends, are you generically converting the data to JSON, or is the JSON structure known to you at this time? If the latter, there is no reason you couldn't represent the same data in database tables. Or, if you really want to store the JSON documents, consider using a JSON store like Mongo or Postgres hstore.